# Creating a json array and json items with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I made a simple javascript class like this:

```
function Horse() {
    this.color = 'brown';
    this.speed = 'somewhat slow';
}
```

I attached a few instances to some elements, like this:

```
$("#horse1").data('d', new Horse());
$("#horse2").data('d', new Horse());
$("#horse3").data('d', new Horse());
```

now I want to create a JSON array with a JSON representation of each horse object. So I'm doing this:

```
// How do I create an empty JSON array here?:
var myJsonArray = ?;

var children = $("#horses").children();
for (var i = 0, m = children.size(); i < m; i++) {
    var panel = children[i];
    var horse = $(panel).data('h');

    // And how do I create a JSON rep of my horse here?
    var myJsonHorse = new JsonHorse(?);

    // Finally, how do I add it to the json array?
    myJsonArray.push(myJsonHorse);
}
```

yeah my end goal is to have a single json array of all the horses after iterating over all the children - not sure if this should be done in plain javascript or in jquery?

Thanks

---------------- Edit -------------------

Sorry, my end goal is to then convert the array to a string, so I have one large json array converted to a string that I can submit to an ajax call that will get processed by my server.

Comment: What are you doing with the object afterwards? A normal array seems to be appropriate here, so I'm not sure what you're after/what the end-game is.

Comment: Oh yeah I want to make it one long json string so I can use it in an ajax call, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To declare an array you just need the Array Literal notation:

```
var myArray = [];
```

The `push` method will work without problems.

Another possibility is to use the [`$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method:

```
var myArray = $("#horses").children().map(function (index, el) {
  return $(el).data('d');
}).get();
//  Will return an array containing:
//  [{"color":"brown","speed":"somewhat slow"},
//   {"color":"brown","speed":"somewhat slow"},
//   {"color":"brown","speed":"somewhat slow"}]
```

Check an example [here](http://jsbin.com/ohote4/2/edit).

Then to convert that array to a JSON string, you can use the `JSON.stringify` method (available natively on almost all browsers, for IE < 8 you can use [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js)).

Comment: +1 - Not that it makes a huge difference, but `$.data(el, 'd')` would be a lot more efficient in this case, no need to create the jQuery wrappers unless you need to.

Comment: That pretty much looks like what I need, but how do I make that array a string? I want to send it to a server-side script, and I hope to deserialize it server-side to operate on the individual horse objects there, thanks.

Comment: @user246114: You need to use the `JSON.stringify` method to convert that array and the object elements it has to JSON, that method is natively available on all browsers except IE <= 7, you can add the [json2.js](http://www.json.org/json2.js) library to your page to make it work on IE <= 7.